# IFERROR in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2003

I understand from reading a couple of threads that `IFERROR` in Excel 2003 is preformed by an `IF(ISERROR)`. The code I am trying to replicate from Excel 2007+ is:

```
=IFERROR(A1, "")
```

I know there must be a simple solution to translating this to `IF(ISERROR)`, but I have had no avail. Advice would be greatly received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel 2003 equivalent of `=IFERROR(A1,"")` is `=IF(ISERROR(A1),"")`. See [=IS](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665). But neither version of that formula is very useful. A little more useful would be something like `=IF(ISERROR(A1),0)` where an error in `A1`, perhaps resulting from dividing by zero, is elsewhere (ie in the cell with the formula) displayed as **0**.

The trouble with the single comma is that if ISERROR() is false (ie `A1` is not an error) this returns FALSE - not particularly helpful but relatively confusing!

So these formulae are normally used with another formula instead of `A1`. That is, one formula is wrapped around another. The later Excel version might have `=IFERROR(A1/B1,"")`. Thus, if `A1` contained **1** and `B1` **2**, the result would be **0.5** whereas if `A1` then were changed to become **#REF!** the result would be blank (nothing visible in the cell with the formula). The later version is brief way of writing `=IF(ISERROR(A1/B1),"",A1/B1)` (still valid in later versions) - which is the Excel 2003 equivalent.

Comment: Link for see 'IS' is broken